# PHP PDO not returning correct data from .mdb table

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am trying to retrieve rows from a .mdb database table.  It is returning the correct column names but I am only receiving 1 row (of 332) and only the "Area Code" column as an exponent.  I am using [this database](http://databases.about.com/library/databases/areacodes.mdb).  I have renamed it to ac.mdb and the table to codes just for ease of programming.

My Code:

```
<?php
    $dbName = "ac.mdb";
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
        die("Could not find database file.");
    }
    try {   
        $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=AccessMDB; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo 'Connected to database<br />';

        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM codes");
        echo ($sql->execute()) ? "Executed" : "Not Executed";

        $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    } catch (PDOException $exception) { 
        echo $exception->getMessage(); 
        exit; 
    } 
?>
```

My result is:

```
Connected to database
Executed
array(2) {
  ["Area Code"]=>
  string(22) "2.0100000000000000e+02"
  ["Region"]=>
  NULL
}
```

If I change the fetch to a fetchAll I get 332 rows but with similar data:

```
Connected to database
Executed
array(332) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Area Code"]=>
   string(22) "2.0100000000000000e+02"
    [0]=>
    string(22) "2.0100000000000000e+02"
    ["Region"]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Area Code"]=>
    string(22) "2.0200000000000000e+02"
    [0]=>
    string(22) "2.0200000000000000e+02"
    ["Region"]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Area Code"]=>
    string(22) "2.0300000000000000e+02"
    [0]=>
    string(22) "2.0300000000000000e+02"
    ["Region"]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
//And so on....
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the wrong return?

Comment: Each number returned is slightly different, look at the 100's decimal place. The problem is that your data is not being interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So, the fields in the table are:

[Area Code]  Double
[Region]     Text, 255

You have two problems:

- The area code field is coming back in scientific notation; you'll
  need to format that to be a 3 digit number with no decimal.
- More confusing is that Region is coming back NULL all of the time.
  None of the rows have a NULL region field.

My guess: `var_dump` is just dumping the output badly. Instead of using `var_dump`, try iterating through the results and printing actual values from the arrays.

Something like this should do:

```
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row){
    foreach ($row as $key => $val){
        print "$val";
    }
}
```

In other words, my theory is that $result actually contains valid data, but the `var_dump()` method is just doing a poor job of giving you debugging output.

Comment: I changed your reply to this for cleanliness.. 

$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($result as $row){
      foreach ($row as $key => $val){
          print "$key = $val<br />";
      }
 }

I get..

Connected to database
Executed
Area Code = 2.0100000000000000e+02
Region = 
Area Code = 2.0200000000000000e+02
Region = 
Area Code = 2.0300000000000000e+02
Region = 
Area Code = 2.0400000000000000e+02
Region = 
Area Code = 2.0500000000000000e+02
Region = 

and so on..  Not sure how to format a comment so it looks good, sorry.

Comment: Well, that shoots my theory in the foot. Clearly region is actually NULL under the hood.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm looking at this table in access, and nothing is jumping out at me as odd; none of the rows even have zero-length strings in the Region field. *still pondering*

Comment: Does anything change if you explicitly request those columns, instead of using `select *`? You may need to wrap `Area Code` in brackets: `select [Area Code], Region`

Comment: Oh.. I think you've been querying against the wrong table! Try this: `$sql = $db->prepare("select * from [Area Codes]");` Unless of course you just renamed it. :)

Comment: I did rename it because I wasn't sure how to handle the space.  If I don't use a *, I get no results back and strangely enough, I don't even get the Executed (or Not Executed) message.  Could it be something that is not installed properly on the server regarding PDO?  I would think, if that were the case, it wouldn't work at all, though.  Thank you for your efforts!